# How to get rid of this extra white space for my div?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I create this app with `create-react-app cli` and I cannot get rid of these extra white spaces at top, left and right side of my main container. Take a look at the screenshot below. I have only one `div` for this app yet and I have the following css for the div.

```css
.mainContainer{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 background-color: black;
}
```

What I have tried is setting both margin and padding for 0px, but neither of them works.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
```

Comment: Oops.. I did not think about it :) Thanks. By the way, is there anyway I can set the height of html or body element to 100% height of screen size in CSS?

Comment: Yes, you can do height: 100vh

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the page, select Inspect and you will be able to see where this margin/padding is coming from. A console will appear, move your mouse over the HTML elements to see a color overlay over the page element. You will be able to see what CSS is doing this and adjust it.

I think you will be able to get rid of it by doing this `.mainContainer { padding: 0, margin: 0 }` but maybe you will only have to reset the padding or the margin, not both.